# an activity Crash on API 19

Tags: android, crash

my app has an activity as below:
but this activity Crash in android 4.4 (api 19).but it works on other api,
app min sdk is api8 and target api 15.
what is wrong with my activity?

this activity has two imageView that one one of them can move and zoom and rotate by touch.

```
public class ArusiActivity extends Activity implements View.OnTouchListener {

//----------------------------------------------------camera(
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST     = 1888;
private ImageView        img_ax;
Uri                      imageUri;
Bitmap                   thumbnail;
//---------------------------------------------------camera)

//---------------------------------------------------gallery(
private static int       RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1 = 1;
//---------------------------------------------------gallery)

//---------------------------------------------------save(
View                     relative;
Bitmap                   bitmap;
//---------------------------------------------------save)

//----------------------------------------------------select frame(
private static int       RESULT_FRAME       = 1333;
//----------------------------------------------------select frame)

//------------------------------------------------------touch(
// these matrices will be used to move and zoom image
private Matrix           matrix             = new Matrix();
private Matrix           savedMatrix        = new Matrix();
// we can be in one of these 3 states
private static final int NONE               = 0;
private static final int DRAG               = 1;
private static final int ZOOM               = 2;
private int              mode               = NONE;
// remember some things for zooming
private PointF           start              = new PointF();
private PointF           mid                = new PointF();
private float            oldDist            = 1f;
private float            d                  = 0f;
private float            newRot             = 0f;
private float[]          lastEvent          = null;
//---------------------------------------------------touch)
//-----------------------------------------------------frame(
String                   Frame_Num;
String                   Frame_Name;
int                      Frame_Number;

private ImageView        img_frame;
//-----------------------------------------------------frame)

OnClickListener          frame              = new OnClickListener() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                                    Intent myvol_idd = new Intent(ArusiActivity.this, Frames.class);
                                                    startActivityForResult(myvol_idd, RESULT_FRAME);
                                                    // finish();
                                                    overridePendingTransition(R.drawable.slide_in, R.drawable.slide_out);

                                                }
                                            };

OnClickListener          gallery            = new OnClickListener() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                                    Intent i = new Intent(
                                                            Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                                                    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1);
                                                    overridePendingTransition(R.drawable.slide_in, R.drawable.slide_out);

                                                }
                                            };
OnClickListener          camera             = new OnClickListener() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                                                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                                                    values.put(MediaColumns.TITLE, "New Picture");
                                                    values.put(ImageColumns.DESCRIPTION, "From your Camera");
                                                    imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                                                            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                                                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                                                    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                                                    overridePendingTransition(R.drawable.slide_in, R.drawable.slide_out);

                                                }
                                            };
OnClickListener          save               = new OnClickListener() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                                    relative = findViewById(R.id.relative);
                                                    relative.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                                                    relative.buildDrawingCache();
                                                    Bitmap bitmap = relative.getDrawingCache();

                                                    Save savefile = new Save();
                                                    savefile.SaveImage(ArusiActivity.this, bitmap);
                                                    relative.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

                                                }
                                            };
OnClickListener          next               = new OnClickListener() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                                                    if (Frame_Num != null && Integer.parseInt(Frame_Num) < 56) {
                                                        Frame_Number = Integer.parseInt(Frame_Num);
                                                        Frame_Number++;
                                                        Frame_Num = "" + Frame_Number;
                                                    } else if (Frame_Num == null) {
                                                        Frame_Number = 2;
                                                        Frame_Num = "2";

                                                    }
                                                    else if (Frame_Num != null && Integer.parseInt(Frame_Num) > 55) {
                                                        Frame_Number = 1;
                                                        Frame_Num = "1";

                                                    }
                                                    Frame_Name = "frame" + Frame_Number;
                                                    img_frame.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(Frame_Name, "drawable", getPackageName()));

                                                }

                                            };
OnClickListener          per                = new OnClickListener() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                                                    if (Frame_Num != null && Integer.parseInt(Frame_Num) > 1) {
                                                        Frame_Number = Integer.parseInt(Frame_Num);
                                                        Frame_Number--;
                                                        Frame_Num = "" + Frame_Number;
                                                    } else if (Frame_Num == null) {
                                                        Frame_Number = 56;
                                                        Frame_Num = "56";

                                                    }
                                                    else if (Frame_Num != null && Integer.parseInt(Frame_Num) < 2) {
                                                        Frame_Number = 56;
                                                        Frame_Num = "56";

                                                    }
                                                    Frame_Name = "frame" + Frame_Number;
                                                    img_frame.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(Frame_Name, "drawable", getPackageName()));

                                                }
                                            };


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    img_ax = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_ax);
    img_ax.setOnTouchListener(this);
    img_frame = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_frame);

    Button btn_frame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_frame);
    btn_frame.setOnClickListener(frame);
    Button btn_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
    btn_save.setOnClickListener(save);
    Button btn_camera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_camera);
    btn_camera.setOnClickListener(camera);
    Button btn_gallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_gallery);
    btn_gallery.setOnClickListener(gallery);
    Button btn_next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
    btn_next.setOnClickListener(next);
    Button btn_per = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_per);
    btn_per.setOnClickListener(per);

    /*/-------------------------------------------------get frame from Frames(
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        String Frame_Name = extras.getString("frame_name");
        img_frame.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(Frame_Name, "drawable", getPackageName()));
    }
    */
    //-------------------------------------------------get frame from Frames)

}


//----------------------------------------------------camera-gellery-frame back(
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //camera(
    switch (requestCode) {

        case CAMERA_REQUEST:
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST)
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    try {
                        thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(
                                getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                        String pathpath = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);

                        // String picturePath contains the path of selected Image
                        Bitmap theBitmap = convertBitmap(pathpath);
                        //  Bitmap theBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);

                        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
                        float dis_height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
                        float dis_width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

                        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pathpath, options);
                        float img_height = options.outHeight;
                        float img_width = options.outWidth;

                        float[] values = new float[9];
                        matrix.getValues(values);

                        float scalee = 0f;
                        if (img_height > img_width) {
                            scalee = (dis_height / img_height) / values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];

                        } else {
                            scalee = (dis_width / img_width) / values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
                        }

                        float xxx = 1;
                        float yyy = dis_height / 2;
                        matrix.postScale(scalee, scalee, xxx, yyy);

                        img_ax.setImageBitmap(theBitmap);

                        float[] values2 = new float[9];
                        matrix.getValues(values2);
                        float first_xx = values2[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
                        float first_yy = values2[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

                        float rAngle1 = Math.round(Math.atan2(values[Matrix.MSKEW_X], values[Matrix.MSCALE_X]) * (180 / Math.PI));
                        matrix.postTranslate( -first_xx, -first_yy);
                        matrix.postRotate(rAngle1);//, img_width * scalee / 2, img_height * scalee / 2);
                        Toast ttt = Toast.makeText(ArusiActivity.this, "صفحه گوشی را یک بار لمس کنید", 5);
                        ttt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                        ttt.show();
                        // img_ax.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
                        //   String imageurl = getRealPathFromURI(imageUri);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
    }
    //camera)

    //gallery(
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaColumns.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        // String picturePath contains the path of selected Image
        Bitmap theBitmap = convertBitmap(picturePath);
        //  Bitmap theBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);

        DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
        float dis_height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        float dis_width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, options);
        float img_height = options.outHeight;
        float img_width = options.outWidth;

        float[] values = new float[9];
        matrix.getValues(values);
        //    float first_x = values[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
        //    float first_y = values[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

        //   float first_1 = values[Matrix.MPERSP_0];
        //   float first_2 = values[Matrix.MPERSP_1];
        //   float first_3 = values[Matrix.MPERSP_2];
        //    float first_4 = values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
        //     float first_5 = values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];
        //     float first_6 = values[Matrix.MSKEW_X];
        //     float first_7 = values[Matrix.MSKEW_Y];

        //   Log.i("LOG", "the first_1  " + first_1);
        //   Log.i("LOG", "the first_2  " + first_2);
        //   Log.i("LOG", "the first_3  " + first_3);
        // Log.i("LOG", "the first_4  " + first_4);
        //  Log.i("LOG", "the first_5  " + first_5);
        //    Log.i("LOG", "the first_6  " + first_6);
        //    Log.i("LOG", "the first_7  " + first_7);
        //  Log.i("LOG", "the first_8  " + first_x);
        //   Log.i("LOG", "the first_9  " + first_y);

        float scalee = 0f;
        if (img_height > img_width) {
            scalee = (dis_height / img_height) / values[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];

        } else {
            scalee = (dis_width / img_width) / values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
        }

        // scalee = (dis_width / img_width) / values[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
        float xxx = 1;
        float yyy = dis_height / 2;
        matrix.postScale(scalee, scalee, xxx, yyy);

        //  Log.i("LOG", "the w dis  " + dis_width);
        // Log.i("LOG", "the h dis " + dis_height);
        // Log.i("LOG", "the w img  " + img_width);
        //Log.i("LOG", "the h img " + img_height);
        //Log.i("LOG", "the scalee " + scalee);

        img_ax.setImageBitmap(theBitmap);
        //  matrix.postTranslate( -first_x, -first_y);
        //  matrix.postRotate(r, tx + xc, ty + yc);

        float[] values2 = new float[9];
        matrix.getValues(values2);
        float first_xx = values2[Matrix.MTRANS_X];
        float first_yy = values2[Matrix.MTRANS_Y];

        //   float first_11 = values2[Matrix.MPERSP_0];
        //   float first_22 = values2[Matrix.MPERSP_1];
        //   float first_33 = values2[Matrix.MPERSP_2];
        //   float first_44 = values2[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
        //   float first_55 = values2[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];
        //   float first_66 = values2[Matrix.MSKEW_X];
        //    float first_77 = values2[Matrix.MSKEW_Y];

        //     Log.i("LOG", "the first_11  " + first_11);
        //     Log.i("LOG", "the first_22  " + first_22);
        //     Log.i("LOG", "the first_33  " + first_33);
        //  Log.i("LOG", "the first_44  " + first_44);
        //  Log.i("LOG", "the first_55  " + first_55);
        //  Log.i("LOG", "the first_66  " + first_66);
        // Log.i("LOG", "the first_77  " + first_77);
        //  Log.i("LOG", "the first_88  " + first_xx);
        //  Log.i("LOG", "the first_99  " + first_yy);
        float rAngle1 = Math.round(Math.atan2(values[Matrix.MSKEW_X], values[Matrix.MSCALE_X]) * (180 / Math.PI));
        //    float rAngle2 = Math.round(Math.atan2(values2[Matrix.MSKEW_X], values2[Matrix.MSCALE_X]) * (180 / Math.PI));
        matrix.postTranslate( -first_xx, -first_yy);
        matrix.postRotate(rAngle1);//, img_width * scalee / 2, img_height * scalee / 2);
        //  matrix.postRotate( -d, img_height * scalee / 2, img_width * scalee / 2);
        //  Bitmap bm_2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm_1, 0, 0, bm_1.getWidth(), bm_1.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        //  Log.i("LOG", "the r1  " + rAngle1);
        // Log.i("LOG", "the r2  " + rAngle2);
        Toast ttt = Toast.makeText(ArusiActivity.this, "صفحه گوشی را یک بار لمس کنید", 5);
        ttt.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        ttt.show();
    }
    //gallery)

    //frame back
    if (requestCode == RESULT_FRAME && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

        Frame_Num = data.getStringExtra("frame_num");
        Frame_Name = "frame" + Frame_Num;
        img_frame.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(Frame_Name, "drawable", getPackageName()));
        overridePendingTransition(R.drawable.slide_in, R.drawable.slide_out);
    }
    //frame back
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------camera-gallery-frame back)
/*   public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
       String[] proj = { MediaColumns.DATA };
       Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
       int column_index = cursor
               .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
       cursor.moveToFirst();
       return cursor.getString(column_index);
   }*/

//--------------------------------------------------------------------touch(
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // handle touch events here
    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            mode = DRAG;
            lastEvent = null;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            oldDist = spacing(event);
            if (oldDist > 10f) {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                midPoint(mid, event);
                mode = ZOOM;
            }
            lastEvent = new float[4];
            lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
            lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
            lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
            lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
            // Log.i("LOG", "the xxxx img  " + lastEvent[0]);
            // Log.i("LOG", "the yyyy img " + lastEvent[2]);
            d = rotation(event);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            mode = NONE;
            lastEvent = null;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (mode == DRAG) {
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                float dx = event.getX() - start.x;
                float dy = event.getY() - start.y;
                matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);

            } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                float newDist = spacing(event);
                // Log.i("LOG", "newDist" + newDist);
                if (newDist > 10f) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float scale = (newDist / oldDist);
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    // Log.i("LOG", "the x  " + mid.x);
                    // Log.i("LOG", "the y  " + mid.y);

                }
                if (lastEvent != null && event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                    newRot = rotation(event);

                    float r = newRot - d;
                    float[] values = new float[9];
                    matrix.getValues(values);
                    float tx = values[2];
                    float ty = values[5];
                    float sx = 1;//values[0];
                    float xc = (view.getWidth() / 2) * sx;
                    float yc = (view.getHeight() / 2) * sx;

                    matrix.postRotate(r, tx + xc, ty + yc);

                }
            }
            break;
    }
    view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    return true;

}


/**
 * Determine the space between the first two fingers
 */
private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
    return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
}


/**
 * Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers
 */
private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
    float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
    point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}


/**
 * Calculate the degree to be rotated by.
 * 
 * @param event
 * @return Degrees
 */
private float rotation(MotionEvent event) {
    double delta_x = (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
    double delta_y = (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
    double radians = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);
    return (float) Math.toDegrees(radians);
}


//--------------------------------------------------------------------touch)

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //Display alert message when back button has been pressed
    backButtonHandler();
    overridePendingTransition(R.drawable.slide_in, R.drawable.slide_out);

    return;
}


public void backButtonHandler() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            ArusiActivity.this);
    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("خروج");
    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("میخواهید خارج شوید؟");
    // Setting Icon to Dialog
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.exit);
    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("بله",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                    overridePendingTransition(R.drawable.slide_in, R.drawable.slide_out);
                }
            });
    // Setting Negative "NO" Button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("خیر",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Write your code here to invoke NO event
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}


//--------------------------------
//---------------------------------
//----------------------------------
public static Bitmap convertBitmap(String path) {

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    BitmapFactory.Options bfOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bfOptions.inDither = false; //Disable Dithering mode
    bfOptions.inPurgeable = true; //Tell to gc that whether it needs free memory, the Bitmap can be cleared
    bfOptions.inInputShareable = true; //Which kind of reference will be used to recover the Bitmap data after being clear, when it will be used in the future
    bfOptions.inTempStorage = new byte[32 * 1024];

    File file = new File(path);
    FileInputStream fs = null;
    try {
        fs = new FileInputStream(file);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        if (fs != null)
        {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fs.getFD(), null, bfOptions);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (fs != null) {
            try {
                fs.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return bitmap;
}


//----------------
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String res = null;
    String[] proj = { MediaColumns.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        ;
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
        res = cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    cursor.close();
    return res;
}
```

}

Comment: Examine LogCat and see where you are crashing and why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: I dont have an android 4.4 device.and in other api it works fine

Comment: If you want to fix a problem with Android 4.4, you will need to test your app on Android 4.4, whether on hardware or on an emulator.

Comment: Wow so much code. Why don't you put the logcat

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right.

Problem is with your manifest.xml file.
Change your targetSdkVersion to 19.
Example: android:targetSdkVersion="19"

Comment: I want my app work for api 8 to 19....i put the minSDK to 8 and TargegSDK to 19 in manifest.should I change the target in properties/android too?

Comment: this activity crash in samsung S5,but in emulator android 4.4.2 work ok.

Comment: yup change the target in properties/android also. And before running the activity in Samsung S5 clear the memory and re install the app again and run it may work.